# zoom with javascript and localstorage

Tags: javascript, zooming, local-storage

I'm trying to script a zoom but in fact I would like to save in memory all preferencies from my users, also I would like to use localstorage in order to save the parameter of their zoom level.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
 <script language=javascript1.2 type=text/javascript><!-- 
var windowToAdjust = ( window.external && window.external.menuArguments ) ? window.external.menuArguments.top : window; 

function focusNorm() { if( window.document.forms[0]['N'+windowToAdjust.screen.width+''] ) { window.document.forms[0]['N'+windowToAdjust.screen.width+''].focus(); } } 

function setZoom(oSelect) { 
if( oSelect.selectedIndex ) { 
if( windowToAdjust.document.body ) { 
if( windowToAdjust.document.body.style ) { 
if( parseInt( oSelect.options[oSelect.selectedIndex].value ) > 100 ) { 
if( !window.confirm( 'All \'drop-down\' select inputs on the page you are adjusting will no longer operate correctly. Resize anyway?' ) ) { oSelect.options[0].selected = true; return; } 
} 
windowToAdjust.document.body.style.zoom = oSelect.options[oSelect.selectedIndex].value + '%'; 
if( window.external && window.external.menuArguments ) { window.close(); } 
} 
} 
} 
} 
//--></script> 
<script language=javascript type=text/javascript><!-- 
// Par DAVID HOUSTIN www.houstin.info // 
var initiale=100; 
function Loupe(plusoumoins) { 
var add=10; 
if (plusoumoins==1) { 
initiale=initiale + add; 
localStorage['zoom'] = initiale + add; 
} 
if (plusoumoins==0) { 
initiale=initiale - add; 
localStorage['zoom'] = initiale + add; 
} 
window.setZoom; 
if( windowToAdjust.document.body ) { 
if( windowToAdjust.document.body.style ) { 
windowToAdjust.document.body.style.zoom = localStorage.getitem['zoom'] + '%'; 
if( window.external && window.external.menuArguments ) { window.close(); } 
} 
} 
} 
//--></script>
```

for the local storage in order to save the value of the zoom i've done this

```
 initiale=initiale + add; 
    localStorage['zoom'] = initiale + add;
```

But when I try to receive the local storage value I've done that:

```
   windowToAdjust.document.body.style.zoom = localStorage.getitem['zoom'] + '%';
```

But it says to me `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'zoom' of undefined`

I'm looking for to find an issue, but I don't know how to solve it.

Best regards.

SP/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getItem is a function, so you should call it like

```
localStorage.getItem('zoom')
```

Notice the () instead of [] and also the camelCase of getItem.

Comment: thanks for the help. a Lot ! Actually it works, but when I input the button for the zoom it does not save the level of the zoom that has been imputed.

Comment: It should be getItem as I mentioned (in camelCase, the I in capitals) instead of getitem (lowercase i).

Comment: thanks for the help. a Lot ! Actually it works, but when I input the button for the zoom it does not save the level of the zoom that has been imputed.

Comment: That's another issue, so better posted in a separate question!